# How set or enable/disable the Extra Dim feature programmatically since Android 12?

Tags: android, screen-brightness

As far as I know, Android has an Extra Dim feature to set the screen brightness. Does any one know how set or enable/disable the Extra Dim feature programmatically in Android?

I use this code to set the normal brightness values (0-255), but I don't know how to manage the Extra Dim feature:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(MyContext.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, Value);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extra dim, that's the standard brightness setting

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://wccftech.com/how-to/how-to-extra-dim-your-screen-brightness-beyond-minimum-on-android-phone/#:~:text=The%20new%20Extra%20Dim%20feature,software%20from%20third%2Dparty%20sources.

Comment: The code you posted is just the standard brightness setting.  It has nothing to do with any extra dim feature.

Comment: That is why I am asking if somebody knows how to use that feature by code. Let me rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

As of now it seems impossible without first aquiring access to secure settings using ADB

The "reduce_bright_colors_activated" secure setting can then be changed.

I also had the idea to create an app that interacts with that setting however requiring (most) users to first use ADB is something that won't work. I don't think this should be a secure setting but unfortunately it is.

[Source (Tasker)](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/qcwgo0/automate_android_12s_new_extra_dim_feature_with/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)